# signal reconstruction

Tags: signal-analysis, python, lowpass-filter, reconstruction

I'm new to DSP so the question might seem a little bit stupid: When using a low pass filter (say Butterworth filter) with Python, I came across an algorithm with which I can reconstruct my signal after filtering (from scipy.lfilter). I'm just wondering how the signal is reconstructed. I thought they used Fourier transform but it's not mentioned.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you think you can make your question a bit more specific? It may have been one of many things, including [plain simple filter design by inverting the frequency response](https://www.dspguide.com/ch17/1.htm) of the [typical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter) Butterworth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with A_A. Just take deeper in Butterworth filter design and this [article](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_8.html) may help you to understand better.